# GDI+, Smaller images?

Tags: .net, image, graphics, gdi+

I create a bitmap from bytes coming via the web and when I downsample it, the resulting Jpeg is still too big even though I use small pixel format.

Does someone know how to manipulate the compression of the image? I had the impression that the saved image is no longer compressed.

Comment: Tony, edit your post by adding the relevant code. It's very possible you're forgetting something. In any case, you'll get more answers, faster, if you include more information, like the size of your images, before and after you use your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not mention in your original post how you are saving your Jpeg. MSDN has a short page on setting compression [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882583.aspx).

I hope I have not misunderstood the question.

Comment: This is really selly, I am studing for Exam 70-536, the book talked about compression like this "You can compress images using GDI+" , the exam is about .Net2, the link u provide is for .Net3.5.

Thanks I need that for my current tasks anyway.